# Javascript - Youtube API detect deleted/blocked videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

How can i check -> if video is deleted / private or embedd not allowed?

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/eyexah/15/edit
**YT API DOC:** https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

**JS code**

```
var params = {
    allowScriptAccess: "always"
},
    atts = {
        id: "youtube_player"
    };

swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/v/SJmrqKOsIpM?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3&autoplay=1', 'youtube', '425', '356', '8', null, null, params, atts);

function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
    if (e !== 1) {
        return;
    }

    var availableQualityLevels = ytp.getAvailableQualityLevels();
    console.log(availableQualityLevels);
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
    window.ytp = document.getElementById("youtube_player");
    ytp.addEventListener('onStateChange', 'onPlayerStateChange')

};
```

Comment: From [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/6WRljEs8fQs) google groups post, it would appear this is not possible in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at play time by listening for the `onError` callback using the Player API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onError

This blog post goes into more details about how you can detect for certain restrictions ahead of time using the Data API: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html

Domain-level whitelists or blacklists are still not exposed via the Data API>